# How do I access my local webcam while my python script is running on a server? (Face-Recognition in real time)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I have a webpage with multiple users and I want each user to be able to log-in using face-recognition.

For this, I have two ways to access the webcam on local systems. First is using JavaScript and the second using OpenCV - Python.

My problem is running face-recognition in real time. The Face-Recognition script is hosted on a server, if I use JavaScript to access my webcam, how do I send each frame to the python script for it to recognize and display the output; or if I use OpenCV in my python script to access my webcam, it fails because the script is running on a server throwing the error
[image]

which completely makes sense because the server has no camera device, but what can be a way-around for this? How do I run face recognition in real time?

This is how I'm using the webcam using imutils:

```
vs = VideoStream(-1).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking images from the video stream in JavaScript. There is a detailed article on how to do that [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos).

Here's how to do that on a high-level, including sending the captured images over the network:

```js
// Send the image data to the server
async function sendImage(image) {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", image);

  return fetch("/some-endpoint", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
  });
}

// Create a base64 image from the stream
function createImage(stream, { width = 640, height = 480 } = {}) {
  // Draw new frame to the canvas
  stream.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  stream.ctx.drawImage(stream.video, 0, 0, width, height);

  // Get base64 image string from canvas and add it the an "image" form field
  return stream.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

// Get video stream and add it to an in-memory video
function createVideoStream() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      video.onloadedmetadata = async () => {
        await video.play();
        resolve({ video, canvas, ctx });
      };
      video.srcObject = stream;
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle errors
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

async function process(stream) {
  const image = await createImage(stream);
  await sendImage(image);
  setTimeout(() => process(stream), 500);
}

createVideoStream().then(process);
```

Note that for increased performance, you could send these images through WebSockets instead of HTTP.

Here's [a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-moon-nv20b?file=/src/index.js) of that code in action (without the server sending part).

Comment: But it's still not in real time is it? I'm recording a video, converting it to images, sending it over to the script on the server and receiving an output?

Comment: You can make this real time by decreasing the `setTimeout` to zero ms and sending the data to your python server through WebSockets.

Comment: @Trollsors I've added a demo link to help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way I would recommend is to implement a python websocket on you server that receives each frame, processes it in real time.

Here is a sample using `FastAPI` WebSockets

```
@router.websocket("/")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            dataTxt = await websocket.receive_text()
            data = json.loads(dataTxt)
            cmd = data['command']
            print("Recieved", cmd)
            frame = decode_to_numpy(data['frame'])
            processed_frame = None
            if cmd == "Monitoring":
                processed_frame = intel.detect(frame=frame, d_face=False, d_holistic=False, d_keyboard=False, d_mouse=False, d_present=False, d_object=False, d_volume=False)
            elif cmd == "Face Recognition":
                processed_frame = intel.detect(frame=frame, d_face=True, d_holistic=False, d_keyboard=False, d_mouse=False, d_present=False, d_object=False, d_volume=False)
            elif cmd == "Object Detection":
                processed_frame = intel.detect(frame=frame, d_face=False, d_holistic=False, d_keyboard=False, d_mouse=False, d_present=False, d_object=True, d_volume=False)
            else:
                processed_frame = intel.detect(frame=frame, d_face=False, d_holistic=False, d_keyboard=False, d_mouse=False, d_present=False, d_object=False, d_volume=False)
                
            encoded_frame = encode_to_json(processed_frame)
            res = {"message": "Frame Processed Successfully", "frame": encoded_frame}
            await websocket.send_text(json.dumps(res))
            print("Sent Response")
    except Exception as e:
        await websocket.close(code=status.WS_1011_INTERNAL_ERROR, reason=f"{e}")
```

The given Sample above sends and receives data in form of JSON string then decode it to a python object for processing and after it sends back the response in the same way.